# What is the extra SSL connection on AWS and bitnami to my IP address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, bitnami

I have a server on AWS and bitnami redirecting SSL on port 443 to `<some-port>`. When I list processes listening on that port, most often I see only one line, and sometimes I see two, with the second one related to my IP and my ISP:

```
$ lsof -i :<some-port>
$ COMMAND     PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
.node.bin <pid> bitnami   <2-digits>u  IPv6 <number>      0t0  TCP *:<some-port> (LISTEN)
.node.bin <pid> bitnami   <2-digits>u  IPv6 <number>      0t0  TCP ip-<some-ip>.<AWS-region>.compute.internal:8443->a<my-ip>.<my-ISP-domain>:<5-digits> (ESTABLISHED)
```

When I run the command immediately after, I only see the first line.

What is this second connection?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here, it seems node is using different interfaces to deploy the application. That's probably how Node.js behaves and you don't need to worry about it. If you check the port 443, you will get the number of processes Apache is using to serve your files.

Comment: @JotaMartos I always thought that Node had its own webserver (I use Express) and not Apache. Could you confirm?

Comment: Yes, Node has its own server but we also include Apache in our stacks so the users can configure the certificates and access their applications easily using the http and https ports.